# What happens in a gas of magnets?

Tags: electromagnetism, statistical-mechanics, ideal-gas

[This SMBC comic](http://www.smbc-comics.com/index.php?id=3668) asks what happens if you make a gas of magnetic particles:

[image]

I was wondering whether anyone has run into actual examples of this or something like it. A classical example similar to this would be a gas comprised of electrically charged particles (possibly in a magnetic field), if the temperature is high then this is essentially plasma physics (which, if memory serves, by it's nature does not include dipole - dipole interactions).

So, are there practical practical, real life situations that can be modelled by a gas of point like dipoles? How do these systems behave?

My own thoughts on this would be

- This gas would effectively behave like a ferromagnet and you would get domains of similarly oriented dipoles.
- The dipole - dipole interaction within those domains is attractive and the domains would collapse forming a larger single dipole.
- In effect this would look very much like the gravitational evolution of a neutral gas except that "gravity" would obey the inverse cube law of dipole - dipole interaction.

Comment: http://newsoffice.mit.edu/2009/magnetic-gas-0918

Answer (score 1):

Dipole gas.

If the dipoles are weak, there are probably many atoms with non-zero dipole moment that can be gas or plasma.

If your dipoles are strong, their strength exceeding normal molecular bonds, I would say that the situation would lead to a condensation of the gas to liquid or solid phase. And you could probably break the bonds (and keep it gaseous) by heating to sufficient temperature $kT \sim E_{bond}$. In that case, there would be no major orientation, I dare to say.

Consider it as hypothetical, many things could have escaped me.

The nice reference of @RedGrittyBrick speaks about $\sim$zero temperature, no Brown motion, no molecule(dipole) collisions.

Answer (score 0):

This morning I was thinking about this idea.
One idea is to modify a Particle -In-Cell simulation of plasma so the particles are little circular rings if charge and Mass that could rotste on their axes . Their translation would be pushed around by Lorenz force but their angular momentum/ magnetic dipole moments would be driven by torque due to magnetic field.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).